# AS 3 Digit Sum. Numerology

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers, digit

Whats the best algorithm to find digit sum on as3? For example to convert 1999 = 1+9+9+9 = 28 = 2+8 = 10 = 1+0 = 1.
I found this on the net, but its for double-digit numbers.

```
 function sumDigits(number) {
    var remainder = number % 10;
    var sum = remainder;
    if(number >= 10) {
        var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
        sum += sumDigits(rest);
    }
    return sum;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as getting the remainder from division by 9, and taking the result of 0 as 9.

```
function sumDigits(num:int):int {
    if (num==0) return 0;
    var red:int=num % 9;
    if (red==0) return 9; else return red;
}
```

The logic behind this answer is simple maths. Whenever you count a sum of digits, you are receiving the value that has the same remainder from division by 9 as the original number. And since you are trying to reduce the sum to a single digit, you can only receive 0-9 as an answer, and only zero has the sum of 0, thus your function should return a number from 1 to 9. These numbers have unique values modulo 9, thus you can get the modulo 9 of original number and derive the result from that.

Comment: Isn't there should be loop or something?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, you want your function to return a single digit that's a sum of digits of a sum of digits ... of a given number. This particular task can be solved without using loops.